# Why xterm did not run in mininet

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualbox, mininet, xterm

I have a problem for a week

1-First i download latest mininet vm image.

2-Ran it on virtualbox.

3 Start GUI by typing startx after gui installation.

4-Mininet to pox traffic goes well.

**Problem starts after this **

5-When i need to look traffic in xterm in mininet it didn't shows or
run xterm.

6-After that, google and stackoverflow some previous information about it and
apply export DISPLAY='10.0.0.2' or maybe something,xterm terminal show on desktop,
remember earlier even xterm terminal didn't shows with Display not set error.

7-Problem is not completely resolved yet,when i type xterm h1 in mininet,mininet terminates without showing any error and clean all nodes.It should show xterm for node h1.

I am using Ubuntu 20.0 OS,mininet image ran on a virtual box.Process all stackoverflow solutions,nothing worked.

I guess it's not a mininet error or something,it should be xterm ports or Display
error or maybe something ?

Comment: I also started going through the mininet tutorial yesterday and have been stuck on the wireshark test ever since. 

 - Got stuck on the xcb error and the suggested fix didn't work using 20.0 img.

 - Got stuck on could not display any X window errors using 18.04.5 img.

 - Tried XMing and X11 forwarding, but made no progress.

I am using Windows and running mininet VM.  SSH-ing to VM with -X param set, but no dice.  xterm has no display error.

Will keep poking away at it as time permits.

Comment: Yeah this is very annoying,even no community help is there for this type of error.SSH is also working for me.

Comment: Definitely not as turn-key as I was expecting.  Not worth stressing over the holidays.  Will check it out again 2022 and post if I find anything.

Comment: @kikuchiyo have you figured it out ?

Comment: no, I haven't resumed discovery work yet.